# BASH - How to read file contents to insert results into mysql WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I'm trying to make a file (call it *accounts*) and have a bash script (call it *name_checker*) loop through each line and make it into multiple strings to store in a variable called '**$NAMES**' for a mysql WHERE IN clause

For example:

My query in my script *name_checker* is basic:

**SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_name IN ('$NAMES')**

The values for the IN statement will need to be separated by commas and put into single quotes.

My *accounts* file will be names separated by newlines:

**NAME1**

**NAME2**

**NAME3**

So I would need my script (*name_checker*) to get rid of the newlines and surround each name with single quotes and separate them with a comma. The desired results when the script is run would be

SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_name IN ('NAME1','NAME2','NAME3')

I am having some difficulty with this and I'm not too familiar with using sed. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done without calling external utilities.

```
cat >Accounts.txt <<XXX
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
XXX
```

Script:

```
while read x; do NAMES="$NAMES,'$x'"; done <Accounts.txt
NAMES=${NAMES:1}
SQL='SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_name IN ('$NAMES')'
echo "$SQL"
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE account_name IN ('NAME1','NAME2','NAME3')
```

Or it can be even simplified removing explicit loop

```
printf -v NAMES ",'%s'" $(<Accounts.txt)
NAMES=${NAMES:1}
echo "$NAMES";
```

Output:

```
'NAME1','NAME2','NAME3'
```

Comment: ^^^ Nifty! I esp like that construct `$(<Accounts.txt)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can use the `mapfile` command (also spelled `readarray`) to pull the entire file into a single array. Then you can expand the array into a single string of comma-separated user names.

```
$ mapfile users < Accounts.txt
$ quotedUsers=( $( printf "'%s' " ${users[@]%?} ) )
$ userString=$( IFS=,; echo "${quotedUsers[*]}" )
```

Comment: `mapfile` is somehow better then using `ARR=($(<Accounts.txt))`? `$(...)` uses `fork(2)` to create new process. `printf -v VAR` does the same without `fork`. The `IFS` trick is nice, but also uses `fork`.

Comment: `mapfile` as a few other options that let you call a callback function after every X lines are read (which, honestly, I've never quite figured out how to use). Using command substitution will fail to give the expected result if any line can be split by the shell into multiple words. `printf -v quotedUsers "'%s' " "${users[@]%?}"` would be fine, I believe (I forgot about that option).

Comment: Actually, `printf -v VAR` only prints a string; you couldn't populate an array in this fashion.

Comment: You will have a variable, in one step! You do not need the second `join` step. Just cut off the extra `,` from the beginning. See my answer. Even mapfile is not needed, the array can be read in the `printf` line.

Comment: If you have that in your answer, then I see no reason to modify mine to duplicate what you already have. There are many ways to accomplish the task; this is just one.

Comment: I did not say your answer is bad, or something. I just would have liked to add a comment that the script uses more resources then needed. Actually I learned a lot with this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well ..

**Accounts.txt**

```
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
```

**Code**

```
NAME=`awk '{print "-"$0"-"}' Accounts.txt| tr "-" "'" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//g'`
echo "$NAME"
```

**Output**

```
'NAME1','NAME2','NAME3'
```

**Note -** 
Use the variable $NAME in your SQL code.

Comment: IMHO using 4 external utilities is a little bit overkill. It can be done in pure [tag:bash].

Comment: or, I would think, in pure awk. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

`names="'$(cat <your file> | sed 's/(\w)\n(\w)/\1\', \'\2/g)'"`

Try that?

:D

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting

unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
syntax error: unexpected end of file


Trying to play around with the closing quotes but I'm unable to find which is needed

Comment: `sed(1)` can read file directly. Do not need to use another processess for `cat(1)`.

Comment: Hey sorry i forgot to escape the second single quote :P I may have bee ntipsy when i posted last ^_^ you sohuld def learn how to use sed tho, `man sed`!

Answer (score 1):

try putting this into your query:

```
echo $NAMES | sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z]*\)/'\1',/g" -e 's/,$//';
```

Example:

```
$ NAMES='Martin John Barbera Holly'
$ echo $NAMES | sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z]*\)/'\1',/g" -e 's/,$//';
'Martin', 'John', 'Barbera', 'Holly'
```

Comment: The $NAMES variable will be directed to another file called 'accounts'

Comment: Sorry I pretty much copied my shell as the example. Pass the file directly to sed - e.g. `sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z]*\)/'\1',/g" -e 's/,$//' accounts` - this should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert your newline-separated entries into single-quoted, comma-separated entries.

```
var=$(awk '{print "\x27"$0"\x27"}' ORS=, accounts_file)
var="${var%,}"
```

Notes:

1. `ORS` stands for output record separator. It's basically the character you use to terminate every line output by awk (default: newline)
2. `\x27` is the hex code for single quotes, to avoid clashing with the outer pair of single quotes (because there cannot be any escape sequence inside single quotes)
3. `${var%,}` is a [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which removes a trailing comma because the `awk` command would leave you with an extra comma.